# Keep black lines, make other colours transparent

Tags: pixelmator

Here is a sample image :

[image]

The white background is actually transparent.

I'd like to keep only the black lines and surfaces, and make all other colours transparent.

Is it possible to do this ?

I'm using Pixelmator, but a photoshop process will be fine !

Comment: You will get very far in photoshop by going from the top menu `Layers > New adjustment layer > Black & white`and slide every slider to the very right, and then start sliding them if anything looks a bit too burned.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the light colors are easier to get rid of with simple contrast adjustment, the dark blues are probably gonna be harder work.

But since this is a comic, it was probably inked first and then colored later. So maybe just ask the publisher of André Franquin for an uncolored version?